# Trouble with setting up my weapons class

Tags: java, class

I am very very new to coding and I need help on an issue that i'm having trouble describing.  I have a weapon class and within that I have defined `maxDamage` along with `name` and `dropChance` in my item class.  I am trying to call upon these and trying to add the max damage to the pre-defined attack damage of the player

This is my item class:

```
package dungeonHunter;

public class Item {
    String itemName;
    int dropChance;

    public Item(String name, int drop){
        itemName = name;
        dropChance = drop;
    }
}
```

This is my Weapon class:

```
package dungeonHunter;

public class Weapon extends Item{

    int maxDamage;

    public Weapon(String name, int mDamage, int dropChance){
        super(name, dropChance);
        maxDamage = mDamage;
    }
}
```

And this is the weapon i'm making:

```
Weapon etherealBlade = new Weapon("Ethereal Blade", 25, 10);
```

And finally this is what I'm trying to do with it:

```
if(rand.nextInt(200) < 10){
            System.out.println("***You have found the Ethereal Blade!***");
            System.out.println("***This increases your damage potential!***");
            attackDamage += etherealBlade;
```

I am trying to call upon the `mDamage` to add it to my players attack damage and I just don't know how.

Comment: If you are using the random class, the nextInt(200) most likely is the reason why your not hitting the if statement as often...Your trying to compare a random number between 1-200 to 10

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to access members of a class (variables or methods) you need to use the point separator.

So your code would be like this:

```
maxDamage += etherealBlade.maxDamage;
```

Comment: You are welcome @Will, and it would be appreciated if you mark the suggestion as an answer by clicking on the green checkmark on the left.